# Twilsock E: 'unsupported protocol: Mb\u000bHà\u0001]ÀÐ\r ver undefined'

Tags: react-native, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I am creating a project using Twilio in React Native 0.46.4 following their example: https://github.com/twilio/TwilioChatJsReactNative

Although, a weird error raises when initializing the API:

```js
import { Client as TwilioChatClient } from "twilio-chat";
import { AccessManager as TwilioAccessManager } from "twilio-common";

const client = new TwilioChatClient(TOKEN, { logLevel: "debug" });
const accessManager = new TwilioAccessManager(TOKEN);

client.initialize().then(() => (
  client.getSubscribedChannels().then(() => {
    // ...
  })
));
```

This is the result:
[Neact Native error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaPdJ.png)

And finally the log:

```
2.195  I: 'Twilsock D:', 'FSM: ', 'startup', ': ', 'none', '>>', 'disconnected'
2.197  I: 'Twilsock D:', 'try to connect to:', 'wss://tsock.twilio.com/v3/wsconnect'
2.199  I: 'Twilsock D:', 'FSM: ', 'userConnect', ': ', 'disconnected', '>>', 'connecting'
2.216  W: Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and correctness issue on Android as it keeps the timer module awake, and timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981 for more info.
2.216  W: (Saw setTimeout with duration 3419784ms)
2.217  W: Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and correctness issue on Android as it keeps the timer module awake, and timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981 for more info.
2.217  W: (Saw setTimeout with duration 3599783ms)
2.244  I: 'EMS D:', 'Token request', { fpa_token: 'xxxx',
2.244  I:   continuation_token: undefined }
2.247  I: 'Chat I:', 'updateToken'
3.096  I: 'EMS D:', 'Token response:', { status: 200,
3.096  I:   headers: 
3.096  I:    { 'content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
3.096  I:      date: 'Wed, 20 Sep 2017 20:09:53 GMT',
3.096  I:      server: 'nginx',
3.096  I:      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=15768000',
3.096  I:      'x-shenanigans': 'none',
3.096  I:      'content-length': '1695',
3.096  I:      connection: 'keep-alive' },
3.096  I:   body: 
3.096  I:    { twilio_rtd_token: 'yyy',
3.096  I:      continuation_token: 'zzz',
3.096  I:      ttl: 3599,
3.096  I:      endpoint_ids: { chat: 'twi1-qqq' },
3.096  I:      status: 
3.096  I:       { status: 'NEW',
3.096  I:         reason: 'continuation token has not been provided' },
3.096  I:      identity: '-----',
3.096  I:      account_sid: 'ACxxx',
3.096  I:      instance_sids: { chat: 'ISxxx' } } }
3.100  I: 'Sync D:', 'POST', 'https://cds.twilio.com/v3/Lists', 'ID:', 'RQYYY'
3.103  I: 'Twilsock I:', 'socket opened'
3.103  I: 'Twilsock D:', 'send request:', 'TWILSOCK V3.0 557\r\n{"id":"511c7f9exxxx","method":"init","token":"yyy","payload_size":0}\r\n'
3.105  I: 'Twilsock D:', 'FSM: ', 'socketConnected', ': ', 'connecting', '>>', 'initialising'
3.299  E: 'Twilsock E:', 'unsupported protocol: Mb\u000bHà�\u0001]ÀÐ\r ver undefined'
3.302  W: 'Twilsock W:', 'FSM: unexpected transition', { '0': 'socketClosed',
3.302  W:   '1': 'unsupported',
3.302  W:   '2': 'unsupported',
3.302  W:   '3': [],
3.302  W:   '4': 100,
3.302  W:   '5': 'event socketClosed inappropriate in current state unsupported' }
3.302  I: 'Twilsock D:', 'FSM: ', 'unsupportedProtocol', ': ', 'initialising', '>>', 'unsupported'
4.225  I: 'Sync D:', 'Establishing intent to subscribe to SHvvv'
4.226  I: 'Chat I:', 'Session created', 'SHnnn'
4.226  I: 'Sync D:', 'GET', 'https://cds.us1.twilio.com/v3/Services/ISzzz/Lists/SHxxx/Context', 'ID:', 'RQxxx'
4.357  I: 'Sync D:', 'Twilsock connection (required for subscription) not ready; waiting…'
```

package.json

```
"twilio-chat": "^1.2.0",
"twilio-common": "^0.1.7",
"twilio-ems-client": "^0.2.6",
"twilio-notifications": "^0.4.4",
"twilio-sync": "^0.5.10",
"twilio-transport": "^0.1.3",
"twilsock": "^0.3.5"
```

This comes from Android Simulator.
Does someone know what is possible happening or what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: works perfect on iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the bug by just updating RN to 0.48.4 which have some WebSocket fixes.

Comment: I have the same issue but changing RN to 0.48.4 didn't solve it. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you cleaned the packager cache and also the build? @ArdaKeskiner

Comment: Yes, but it did not help. I managed to solve the issue by changing core-js version from 2.5.3 to 2.5.2